# How to stop UITextView from scrolling when fingers are lifted (Swift 4)

Tags: ios, swift

I have a textView whose content may exceed the height of the view, so I would like to be able to scroll down, stopping when I want, and to scroll back up when returning after having stopped.

**Problems**:

When scrolling (with two fingers), two things happen:

- the top lines scroll into the view above
- when fingers are lifted from the screen, the view just bounces back to the top.

**Questions**:

- How do I prevent the data from scrolling above the textView frame into the view above it?
- How do I stop the scrolling when they take their fingers off the screen?  What event(s) get called when the user lifts their fingers?

```
import UIKit

class ScrollableView: UIView, UITextViewDelegate {

    var displayData = UITextView()

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)        
        displayData.delegate = self

        getContent()
        calculateFrameBounds()
        displayTallTable()
    }

    func getContent() {
    }

    func calculateFrameBounds() {
    }

    func displayTallTable() {
        displayData.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: w, height: h)        
        self.addSubview(displayData)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not add a UITextView to a scrollView? For more, check out the callbacks in scrollView’s delegate `UIScrollViewDelegate`. Also, you can force scrolling to stop by toggling `scrollView.isScrollEnabled`

Comment: That is where I began, but removed it because ````UITextView```` is already a subclass of ````UIScrollView````.

Comment: You can still set a delegate on your UITextView and observe respond to the callbacks

Comment: Yes, I've got the callbacks working now (see below), but now can't figure out how to stop the scrolling when fingers are lifted.

Answer (score 1):

Use the touchesEnded function, this function is called whenever a touch event is ended.

```
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
            // implement in this function, when fingers are lifted this function is called.
        }
```

Comment: I added this but it does not get called.  I also tried ````touchesCancelled```` but it doesn't get called either.

Comment: Also tried adding ````super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)````, but that didn't help.

Comment: I just discovered that these do get called, but only the superview, not on the UITextView.

Comment: I've added the touch functions (began, ended, cancelled, moved) into ````extension UITextView ```` and they now respond.

Comment: The next question is what do I do within those functions???  How do I stop freeze the view in place when ````touchesEnded```` is called?

Comment: Use `displayData.isUserInteractionEnabled = false` in  your `touchesEnded` function, it may work.

Comment: Unfortunately, no luck there.  I also tried ````displayData.isScrollEnabled = false```` which also did not work.  ````touchesCancelled```` is called more often than ````touchesEnded```` so I tried them in there as well without success.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

To be able to stop and resume scrolling, it turns out that the height of UITextView (`displayData`) needs to be smaller than its contents.  All I needed to do was set its height to that of the UIView containing it.

The UITextView (`displayData`) is inside a UIView container.  To prevent `displayData`'s text from scrolling into the adjacent views (above and below the UIView container) I only had to turn on clipsToBounds on the UIView container like this: `super.clipsToBounds = true` (or check the box in IB).

This is only a partial solution, however. Because I have gaps between the UITextView (`displayData`) and the top and bottom of its UIView container, the data still scrolls off the UITextView and into the gaps of the UIView.

[image]

I have tried all of the following without success:

```
displayData.clipsToBounds = true
displayData.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
displayData.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Any help with this last piece would be greatly appreciated!